# Postman shows error when i add a custom domain name to the environment variable

Tags: node.js, nginx, postman, digital-ocean, domain-name

Sending requests work from my server with my server IP. But now i added a custom domain name and when i try sending get requests to that domain name its keeps on showing an error "Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND www.mydomain.com". Firefox returns a json response when i hit my route, but its not working in postman. I even saw some articles and switched off ssl verfication in postman settings and it's still not working. Can any one help fix this issue.

[image: Screenshot of Postman]

Comment: Maybe you added complete url in {{url}} variable and then still appending the URI like https://example.com/data-as-json/data-as-json.

Comment: @PawanBishnoi It worked now. I didnt do anything new it just worked. I think its because it needed some time for the domain name to activate. Tnx anyways